# Why does a brand new grails app show me notFound.gsp instead of index.gsp?

Tags: linux, grails

This is a brand new app on a fresh install, but I do not see the info page I am expecting to see. I get some errors when running start-app, would this maybe have something to do with the problem? I am trying to teach myself this framework but am confused as to why I am having this problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/97TUZ.png

Thanks for any info you can provide, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, the documentation I'm looking at says that /test/ (the grails project name) should be part of the path, but it is not. Omitting this has it work the way I expect, although I'm not really sure why, or how I would segregate different applications using the URL path.

Comment: "... I'm not really sure why, or how I would segregate different applications using the URL path" - In recent versions of Grails the context root is set to `/`.  If you are deploying multiple applications to the same servlet container, you would map them to different roots and how you do that depends on which servlet container you are using.  Even if you are only deploying one app to the container you could still set the context root if you wanted to for some reason.